Is it possible to stream cloudwatch logs as they happen in the front end?
Scenario:
An aws batch job that can run for up to 30 mins. It will continually create logs, that are send to a cloudwatch logstream thoughout the jobs lifetime.
From the front ends perspective, the user should see the logs as they are created in real time.
I'm thinking of using apigateway websocket, but not sure if there is a better way?

What have you tried? What error did you get when you tried?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.
